# ndarray.view() doesn't work if entries are multidimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional NumPy array of shape `(n, i, j, k, ...)` and I'd like to view it as a list of length `n` with entries of shape `(i, j, k, ...)`. (Makes subsequent computations easier.) Now, [`view()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) works well, but only if the entries are scalars or vectors. It fails if the entries are matrices:

```py
import numpy as np

# okay
a = np.random.rand(7)
b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * 1)))

# okay
a = np.random.rand(7, 2)
b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * 2)))

# fail
a = np.random.rand(7, 2, 3)
b = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * 2 * 3)))
```

```
ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

Any hint on what's going wrong here?

Comment: The last with `3` instead of `2*3` works.  Note the view preserves the number of dimensions, just changing the last to 1.  I haven't used this kind of view, and don't see it's value.  `b` displays as an array of `b'strings'`.

Comment: Is there way to only preserve the leading dimension?

Comment: I don't either of us paid attention to the full error message, `the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.`

Comment: This compound dtype view makes more sense to me - `view(np.dtype([('f0','f8',(3,))]))`.  But it's doing something similar, consolidating the last dimension into one 'record'.  The shape is still (7,2,1).

Comment: How about reshaping to (7,6)?

Comment: Yeah that's probably what it comes down to eventually. Reshape first, and in the end reshape again.

Comment: But don't you have to change `view` back to floats?  I still don't see what this `np.void` view does for you.  `list(a)` is a list of (2,3) arrays.  `[i for i in a]` does the same thing.

Comment: `np.unique` is one the few cases I know of where a view like this used, and even there it has to first reshape to 2d.

Comment: It's indeed for `np.unique`. [Figured out it with reshapes now.](https://github.com/nschloe/npx/blob/main/npx/_main.py#L83)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with view as type np.void? Are you trying to manipulate the bytes?

If you just want to convert a shape `(n, i, j, k, ...)` array into a python list of n elements of shape `(i, j, k, ...)` why not just use [np.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?

```py
a = np.random.uniform(size=(7, 2, 3))
new_a_shape = (-1,) + a.shape[2:] # to get rid of the first dimension
b = np.split(a.reshape(new_a_shape), a.shape[0])
```

results in

```
[array([[0.07452901, 0.4068812 , 0.87074721],
        [0.23739783, 0.67298745, 0.96651022]]),
 array([[0.94348732, 0.004426  , 0.75326683],
        [0.35342782, 0.98006333, 0.46106085]]),
 array([[0.92510793, 0.90671794, 0.34370929],
        [0.42120306, 0.41411307, 0.94946278]]),
 array([[0.49097638, 0.53814849, 0.10396104],
        [0.19402855, 0.31811608, 0.13399161]]),
 array([[0.91071595, 0.3167224 , 0.42786695],
        [0.62646702, 0.68093573, 0.24839687]]),
 array([[0.95266909, 0.13838363, 0.10488899],
        [0.40992171, 0.29816304, 0.31875   ]]),
 array([[0.03371908, 0.29406525, 0.65801023],
        [0.93566766, 0.84455742, 0.40625077]])]
```

Comment: `list(a)` does the same thing, and is faster.

Comment: Cool, I thought list(a) would be equivalent to .tolist(), but you are right!

Comment: Yes, knowing the difference between `list` and `tolist` is useful.  Often `tolist` is more useful, and usually faster.  But this OP has some unusual requirements.